# Not able to commit changes made in ipynb file to github

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

I have a ipynb file that's both on github as well as my PC. I have made changes to the one on my PC, and want to commit those changes. I run the usual commands to do so, and all of they work without any issue. However, none of those changes are reflected in my git repository. On terminal, `git status` shows me `nothing to commit, working tree clean` and hence, `git commit` also seems to be doing nothing. I'm using these commands:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Added ipynb"
git push -u origin master
```

Please tell me where am I wrong. Thanks...

Comment: Check whether the top commit given by `git log -1` on your local is present on the remote repository. If it is, then there's nothing to worry about, all your changes are there on remote. If it isn't, `git push` will push your unpushed commits to the master.

Comment: Maybe a dump question, are you sure that the files are not ignored because of your `.gitignore` settings?

Comment: @Krantisinh no it isn't. And `git push` is not pushing anything. It just says everything is up to date.

Comment: @Moerwald can you please tell me how can I access the `.gitignore` setting? I never heard of it before...

Comment: check whether origin path given by `git remote -v` points to the same remote that you want to push your changes to.

Comment: @Krantisinh yes!

Comment: Are you checking the same branch on remote that has been checked out on local ?

Comment: @Krantisinh I have only one branch on remote as well as local. Running `git checkout master` gives `Already on master`

Comment: Not sure if it'll actually be helpful, but here's a link to my github repo: https://github.com/ak2600/scratchML

Comment: How many commits do you see in your local git log ? What's the hash of latest commit ?

Comment: @Krantisinh 9 total commits. `1f199ea39bd7d3c8d5cf4a5bf89d4c6f82a671db` is the hash

Comment: That means all commits in your local branch are there on remote :) Check the remote repo's second commit. It's the same as of the top commit in your local.

The latest commit in your remote seems missing in your local. To get that, do a `git pull` and you will be all set!

Comment: Or if you don't want that latest commit from remote, do a `git push origin -f` to force push your changes from local. It will overwrite your remote with those changes in local.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote the 2nd one's hash actually... updated the comment later on (but maybe it was too late by then)

Comment: @Krantisinh ugh this is so frustrating. Even on pushing the changes forcibly, its still showing me `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: I can see that it has now  updated your remote successfully. The latest hash on remote is 1f199ea39bd7d3c8d5cf4a5bf89d4c6f82a671db.

Comment: @Krantisinh I saved all my work in a different directory. Cloned the git repo. Cut-pasted my changes in the local directory. Pushed. It worked. Tried changing some stuff in my ipynb file and it's committing perfectly now. I don't know what the issue was, but it seems to be working perfectly now. Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: You are welcome! Actually your last command [force push] did work. Earlier it wasn't working because your remote had different history than your local. A git pull, resolving conflicts if needed and then commit and push would have worked in that case.